# Nginx reverse proxy configuration

Tags: apache, nginx, reverse-proxy

I need nginx to reverse- proxy GET and POST requests of the form:

```
/myapp/path/to/resource
```

to:

```
http://127.0.0.1:9090/path/to/resource
```

I'm trying the following:

```
location /myapp/(.*) {
  rewrite $1;
  proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9090;
}
```

but nginx is returning a HTTP 405 error [not allowed].

Any ideas on how to fix this ? Thanks.

Comment: Was you able to fix this, I have similar problem, I have the same requirements e.g. /myApp1/A to 127.0.0.1:8080/A and /myApp2/A to 127.0.0.1:8081/A

Answer (score 5):

You don't actually need to do a rewrite. You can achieve the same end with the following:

```
location /myapp/ {
  proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9090/;
}
```

Comment: You probably meant to leave the 'myapp' off of the proxy_pass.